# Forward slash or backslash when declaring includes on C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I had always used `<bits/stdc++>` library for my codes, however, I noticed that `<bits\stdc++.h>` works as well on CodeBlocks 16.01 on GNU GCC compiler, Windows 7/10 environment.

My question is **Which of those is right, and if not both, why is one wrong?**

I have successfully compiled code with that include in more than one computer.

Comment: Windows can handle both backward \ and forward slashes `/` in its paths. However, most uses forward slashes since it's the most compatible with other systems.

Comment: Be more specific about your problem, it is very vague. Give examples.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you write an answer for that question, so that I could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Which of them is right, if the both are not, why is one of them right and the other one not?**

Only the forward slash `/` is *right*. Compilers under Windows systems use an extension that can handle both.